# Uniqueness of traceless symmetric operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $S:V^2\to V^2$ be a symmetric operator defined into a $2$-dimensional vector space $V$. Suppose that $S$ is traceless, that is, the trace of $S$ is null and for $x,y\in V$, such that $x\neq 0$, we have $Sx=y$.

My question is: There is $R:V^2\to V^2$ a traceless symmetric operator, $R\neq S$, such that $Rx=y$? Ie, the condition $x\neq 0$ and $Sx=y$ becomes $S$ unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming $V$ is a vector space over a "real" field, that is, over some field $\Bbb F$ with $\Bbb Q \subset \Bbb F \subset \Bbb R$; this assumption is in accord with my understanding of the usual meaning of he word "symmetric" as applied to linear operators, which word is, to my knowledge, most typically used in the "real" context.

Having said this, we may resolve this question by representing $S$ and $R$ in matrix form.  Since $S$ is traceless and symmetric, we may write

$S = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{bmatrix}, \tag 1$

where $a, b \in \Bbb F$; now if

$x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb F^2, \tag 2$

and

$y = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb F^2, \tag 3$

the equation

$Sx = y \tag 4$

becomes

$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}, \tag 5$

which when written out in terms of components is

$ax_1 + bx_2 = y_1, \tag 6$

and

$bx_1 - ax_2 = y_2; \tag 7$

we observe that (6)-(7) may be written as a two-dimensional system in $a$ and $b$, setting

$X\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ -x_2 & x_1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}; \tag 8$

furthermore,

$\det X = x_1^2 + x_2^2 \ne 0 \; \text{if} \; x \ne 0; \tag 9$

thus $X^{-1}$ exists; it follows that $a$ and $b$, and hence $S$, are uniquely determined by (4), so we may conclude that

$R = S. \tag {10}$

***NB:***  Does a similar result hold over complex fields $E$ such that $\Bbb Q(i) \subset \Bbb E \subset \Bbb C$?  Perhaps if we replace the word "symmetric" with "hermitian"? inquiring minds want to  know . . . ***End of Note.***

***Note Added in Edit, Wednesday 27 September 2017 9:23 PM PST:***  This in response to a further question posed by our OP Irddo in his comment(s) below.
If instead of hypothesizing $S$ be traceless, we wish to find $S$ such that $\text{Tr} S = t \in \Bbb F$, we can set

$T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & t \end{bmatrix} \tag{11}$ and look at the equation

$(S + T) x = y \tag{12}$

for given $x$ and $y$.  Then

$Sx = y - Tx, \tag{13}$

and we now obtain a system

$X\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = y - Tx, \tag{14}$

which may be solved as before:

$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = X^{-1}(y - Tx). \tag{15}$

One *caveat*:  we have to be a little careful to avoid the situation

$\det(S + T) = ta - (a^2 + b^2) = 0, \tag{15}$

or we won't necessarily be able to choose $x$ and $y$ independently.  Also, $a$ and $b$ will now exhibit a nonlinear dependence on $x$; I leave the details to my readers to discover.  ***End of Note.***

Comment: Perfect. Is it possible to find something for symmetric operator with constant trace? I will try to do, but have you any help? Thanks so much.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant trace"?  That it is a given value $t$?  You could try following what I did here and then you'd perhaps get a system whose solutions were $t$-dependent?  I'm not sure . .  but thanks for the kind word and the "acceptance".  Cheers!

Comment: I means that the trace of S is some constant non-zero.

Comment: You'd get $S = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & t - a \end{bmatrix}$, get it?  It could be pursued; let me know if you get something, OK?  Thanks again! :)

Comment: If I take the matrix that you said, I can't become its in something like the equation (8) above. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure what would happen, you'd have to try and see where it leads.  It wouldn't be *exactly* the same . . . but I think you may be able to get $a, b$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: Thanks again for the big help!!

Comment: @RobertLewis I believe $x^tx\neq 0$ is a necessary condition for the existence of such an $S$ in the first place, and as your construction shows, it is a sufficient condition.  If it were Hermitian matrices instead, then $x^*x\neq 0$ would be the condition, which is true when $x\neq 0$, and your construction would carry through.  It isn't necessary to construct an $S$ to prove uniqueness, but it is nice to see there is a formula.  Do you have any idea why $(a,b)=X^{-1}y$ is $a+bi=(y_1+iy_2)/(x_1-ix_2)$? (if I got it right, and assuming $a,b,x,y$ real)

Comment: @KyleMiller:  I haven't had more time to think about this, but if I come up with anything I'll let you know.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If $R,S:V\to V$ are both traceless symmetric operators such that $Rx=Sx$ for some nonzero $x$, then $R-S:V\to V$ is a traceless symmetric operator such that $(R-S)x=0$.  If we can show that $R-S=0$, then we know $R=S$.  Let $T=R-S$.

We have $Tx=0$, and since $T$ is symmetric, $x^tT=0$, too.  Let $y\in V$ be a vector linearly independent of $x$.  So far we have $x^tTx=0$, $x^tTy=0$, and $y^tTx=0$.

Trace does not depend on the basis, so $\operatorname{tr}T=\frac{1}{x^tx}x^tTx+\frac{1}{y^ty}y^tTy=\frac{1}{y^ty}y^tTy$.  Tracelessness implies the last thing we need: $y^tTy=0$. **Note:** this depends on these denominators not being zero, which is not a problem over $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $\{x,y\}$ is a basis of $V$, we can conclude $T=0$, and therefore $R=S$.

This argument carries over immediately to the case $\operatorname{tr}R=\operatorname{tr}S$ because we did not rely on the tracelessness of $R$ or $S$, only that $\operatorname{tr}(R-S)=0$.